# User Defined Non-Type Parameter Workaround

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, constexpr

A while back I learned you could pass literals into a template like so:

```
template <int x>
class myClass { };

//Later
myClass<12> var;
```

Now I have defined my own int type and want to do the same thing with that....but it is turning out to be a headache

I am trying to achieve....something like this:

```
class myIntType;

template <myIntType val>
class Other{
};
```

Unfortunately this is illegal :(

So another shot at it is instead of giving an actual instance, pass a function that will return an instance (because this is an integer type anyways....so we don't care if two instances are the actually same instance so much):

```
template<myIntTypeT(*Val)()>
class Other{
};
```

And then you use it like this:

```
constexpr myIntType foo() { return 12_mit; } 
   //_mit operator returns a myIntType var
Other<foo> other;
```

There are a couple downsides with this approach:

- `Other<foo>` and `Other<bar>` are different types even if `bar` mirrors whatever `foo` gives (this I am OK with)
- It is very inelegant (this I am not so fine with)

Unfortunately that is a very clunky use.  So my next attempt is to take a lambda function and put it into the template:

```
Other<[](){ return 12_mit; }> other;
```

But that fails because lambdas are not `constexpr`s....

So is there another more elegant solution to pass an *instance* of a user defined type into a template?

Comment: Does myIntType have a constexpr ctor?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to pass a reference to an instance of `MyIntType` as the template argument:

```
class MyIntType {
public:
  MyIntType () {}
};

template <const MyIntType & val>
class Other {};

const MyIntType foo;

int main () {
  Other<foo> other;
}
```

Another option would be to pass a pointer to an instance of `MyIntType` as the template argument:

```
class MyIntType {
public:
  MyIntType () {}
};

template <const MyIntType * val>
class Other {};

const MyIntType foo;

int main () {
  Other<&foo> other;
}
```

Note that in these simple examples, the constructor of `MyIntType` does not need to be `constexpr`.

According to the C++ standard (section 14.3.2, clause 1):

> A *template-argument* for a non-type, non-template *template-parameter* shall be one of:
>
> - for a non-type *template-parameter* of integral or enumeration type, a converted constant expression (5.19) of the type of the *template-parameter*; or
> - the name of a non-type *template-parameter*; or
> - a constant expression (5.19) that designates the address of a complete object with static storage duration and external or internal linkage or a function with external or internal linkage, including function templates and function *template-ids* but excluding non-static class members, expressed (ignoring parentheses) as *`&` id-expression*, where the *id-expression* is the name of an object or function, except that the `&` may be omitted if the name refers to a function or array and shall be omitted if the corresponding *template-parameter* is a reference; or
> - a constant expression that evaluates to a null pointer value (4.10); or
> - a constant expression that evaluates to a null member pointer value (4.11); or
> - a pointer to member expressed as described in 5.3.1; or
> - a constant expression of type `std::nullptr_t`.

The examples above fall into the category of:

> A constant expression that designates the address of a complete object with static storage duration and external or internal linkage.